# Configure Apache to associate subdirectory/subdomain to Flask port

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, flask

I am running Flask on a server that has Apache installed. Users are accustomed to accessing websites on the server using subdirectories such as [www.domain.com/mysite](http://www.domain.com/mysite).

My question is, can I make Apache show [www.domain.com:5000](http://www.domain.com:5000) when [www.domain.com/mysite](http://www.domain.com/mysite) is accessed **whilst showing [www.domain.com/mysite](http://www.domain.com/mysite) in the address bar**? Up to now I have managed to create a redirection using an .htaccess file in [www.domain.com/mysite](http://www.domain.com/mysite) but the address bar changes to [www.domain.com:5000](http://www.domain.com:5000) which I would like to avoid.

I would be happy to use subdomains instead of subdirectories if it makes a difference (mysite.domain.com).

Comment: You would want to configure apache as a reverse proxy to your Flask application. This way, the visitors will not see the port in the address bar wile accessing your Flask site.

Comment: @RoseHosting Got any pointers on that? I found this but I need a little more help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html